# How Count Row Value in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called `TimeSheet` :

```
Card_No    Name    1    2    3    4
123        GGG    A    P    P    P
123        GGG    A    P    A    P
123        GGG    A    P    P    P
123        GGG    A    A    A    P
```

I want to count total A in one row. Result should be like this

```
Card_No    Name    1    2    3    4    TotalA
123         GGG    A    P    P    P    1
123         GGG    A    P    A    P    2
123         GGG    A    P    P    P    1
123         GGG    A    A    A    P    3
```

How can I do it ? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way

```
SELECT 
      *,
      CASE WHEN [1] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN [2] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN [3] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN [4] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalA
FROM TimeSheet
```

or

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM   (VALUES([1]),
                      ([2]),
                      ([3]),
                      ([4])) V(c)
        WHERE  c = 'A') AS TotalA
FROM   TimeSheet
```

Comment: When i use the first one Its Count the next row A also in same row why ?

Comment: @sandip - You must be mistaken. Both return the same results. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed12f/3) SQL Server 2008 has no functionality to reference the next row in a `SELECT` (In SQL Server 2012 `LAG`/`LEAD` can do this). Maybe you made an error applying it to your actual table/columns feel free to add a screenshot demonstrating the issue.